# press separate edit button to edit cell or row in kendogrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Presently, I am attempting to have an edit button that the user can press to start editing the first cell, then have subsequent presses step through the rest of the cells in a kendogrid.

When I execute this code:

```
function initButtons() {
    // ...
    $("#edit-param-btn").kendoButton().on('click', function (e) { execEditParameter(e) });
    // ...
}

function execEditParameter(e) {
    var row = $("#rule-parameters").data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
     $("#rule-parameters").data('kendoGrid').editRow(row); 
}
```

Here is the UI:

[image]

This is the error I'm receiving when I press edit:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.children is not a function
  at pt.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend._createInlineEditor (http://localhost/Tdm/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js:30:21788)
  at pt.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.editRow (http://localhost/Tdm/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js:30:18039)
  at eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:21)
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:55)
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
  at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:964:21)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting it working by changing execEditParameter to this:

```
function execEditParameter(e) {
    var dataItem = $("#rule-parameters").data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")); 
    var row = $("#rule-parameters").data('kendoGrid').tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
    $("#rule-parameters").data('kendoGrid').editRow(row); 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The above works great for editing the first row, but if I want to edit the row the user has selected so it can select one of multiple rows, then this is better:

```
function execEditParameter() {
    var row = $("#rule-parameters").data('kendoGrid').select();
    $("#rule-parameters").data('kendoGrid').editRow(row); 
}
```